# shuffle and partition in training, validation and testing of a multi-label combined dataset MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning, dataset, training-data

I want to train a Faster R-CNN with 224x224x3 images that are log-scaled mel spectrograms from the UrbanSound8k dataset
The data is already labeled with rectangles.
here's my code:

```
%% imds* are M x 2 tables, 1st column 'imageFileName' 2nd 'label_name' with [x,y,height,width] of the rectangular ROIs 

%% Dataset Extraction: Label tables combining

airConditionerLbl = imdsAirConditioner(:,2:end);
carHornLbl = imdsCarHorn(:,2:end);
childrenPlayingLbl = imdsChildrenPlaying(:,2:end);
dogBarkLbl = imdsDogBark(:,2:end);
drillingLbl = imdsDrilling(:,2:end);
engineIdlingLbl = imdsEngineIdling(:,2:end);
gunShotLbl = imdsGunShot(:,2:end);
jackhammerLbl = imdsJackhammer(:,2:end);
sirenLbl = imdsSiren(:,2:end);
streetMusicLbl = imdsStreetMusic(:,2:end);

%% Combining into boxLabelDs

blds = boxLabelDatastore(airConditionerLbl,carHornLbl,childrenPlayingLbl,dogBarkLbl,drillingLbl,engineIdlingLbl,gunShotLbl,jackhammerLbl,sirenLbl,streetMusicLbl);

%% extract imagesFileName from tables

airConditionerFiles = imdsAirConditioner.imageFilename;
carHornFiles = imdsCarHorn.imageFilename;
childrenPlayingFiles = imdsChildrenPlaying.imageFilename;
dogBarkFiles = imdsDogBark.imageFilename;
drillingFiles = imdsDrilling.imageFilename;
engineIdlingFiles = imdsEngineIdling.imageFilename;
gunShotFiles = imdsGunShot.imageFilename;
jackhammerFiles = imdsJackhammer.imageFilename;
sirenFiles = imdsSiren.imageFilename;
streetMusicFiles = imdsStreetMusic.imageFilename;

%% create the imageDatastore

imds = imageDatastore([airConditionerFiles;carHornFiles;childrenPlayingFiles;dogBarkFiles;drillingFiles;engineIdlingFiles;gunShotFiles;jackhammerFiles;sirenFiles;streetMusicFiles]);
%% combine the datastores
cds = combineDatastore(imds,blds);
```

I want to shuffle and split the data into training, validation and testing and I don't know how and where I can do it in this code.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Does [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help//deeplearning/ug/object-detection-using-faster-r-cnn-deep-learning.html#DeepLearningFasterRCNNObjectDetectionExample-2) help at all?

Comment: Not really. But in the end I managed to solve the problem dividing and organizing data before the datastore creation.